# Finding the Largest through Reduce and Conquer

Tags: java

I have a problem I need help solving, basically, the problem asks me to use a Reduce and Conquer Algorithm to find the largest element.

**Problem Description:** Return the largest element in a non-empty array of integers. We'll use the convention of considering only part of the array that begins at a given index and ends at another. In this way, a recursive call can work through any part of the array. The initial call will pass in index 0 and the index to the last element.

Some of the things I thought of was to approach this problem using recursion but I been struggling with recursion as it is a concept I don't have a full grasp of. Can any one point me into the right direction? Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed. Thank you.

Here is what I thought of so far:
**EDIT: Updated code**

```
public int max(int[] nums, int begin, int end) {

int maxVal = begin;

    if (begin == end) return nums[0];

    else if(begin < end){
      maxVal = max(nums, begin+1, end);
      if (maxVal > nums[end-begin]) return maxVal;
      else return nums[end-begin];
    }
    return maxVal;
  }
```

This would be the outputs:

max([2, 1, -2, 3, 8], 0, 4) → 8

max([6, 2, -4], 0, 2) → 6

max([3], 0, 0) → 3

Comment: Ok first think of your base case or the case where you want to actually return value instead of more recursion.

Comment: Thank you @SamOrozco. I went around the web and found several helpful articles. Here is my code again and it worked. 

`public int max(int[] nums, int begin, int end) {
  
  int maxVal = begin;
  
  if (begin == end) return nums[0];
  
  else if(begin < end){
    maxVal = max(nums, begin+1, end);
    if (maxVal > nums[end-begin]) return maxVal;
    else return nums[end-begin];
  }
  return maxVal;
}
`

Comment: Can you update the question with your new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(max(new int[] { 2, 1, -2, 3, 8 }, 0, 4));
        System.out.println(max(new int[] { 2, 1, -2, 8, 3 }, 0, 4));
        System.out.println(max(new int[] { 2, 1, 8, -2, 3 }, 0, 4));
        System.out.println(max(new int[] { 2, 8, 1, -2, 3 }, 0, 4));
        System.out.println(max(new int[] { 8, 2, 1, -2, 3 }, 0, 4));
    }

    static int max(int[] nums, int begin, int end) {
        if (begin >= end) {
            return nums[end];
        }
        if (nums[begin] > nums[end]) {
            return max(nums, begin, end - 1);
        } else {
            return max(nums, begin + 1, end);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
8
8
8
8
8
```

Comment: Awesome, although I figure it out, I appreciate your solution as it helped me understand it more easily. Thank you!